# How to edin x number of files at once

Tags: linux, string, automation

I have a task to edit about 5k files.
Must remove all strings starting with ?ver=2.35.1 where after the = all the numbers are random.
As I see I need to replace every ?ver= ... with empty string.
I tried with the linux console but I cant specify the random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sed.

```
sed 's/^?ver=[0-9.]\+//' file
```

Explanation:

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `?var=` Matches the string `?ver=` . Here `?` is not considered as a regex meta character.
- `[0-9.]\+` Matches one or more digits or dot.

Comment: ok but how to specify all the files in a folder,not file by bile

Comment: you could use this `find` on the directory where the files you want to modify are located. `find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/^?ver=[0-9.]\+//' {} \;`

Comment: @Skynet that's why i'm on the [top](http://stackoverflow.com/users).  Try to provide an working answer at very first as much as possible :)

Comment: yeah never noticed that ever :)

Comment: Hmm.. this string type is in the files content,not their titles

Comment: it would work on the file contents. Or you could run `sed 's/^?ver=[0-9.]\+//' *.*` . Add `i` param to save the changes made.

Comment: well.. none of the files are edited,also all files are in folders

Comment: did you try this `sed -i 's/^?ver=[0-9.]\+//' *.*`

Comment: Yes I tried that,Its doing something but later no edited files

Answer (score 0):

Learn about [ed](http://www.gnu.org/software/ed/), [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), [gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) and combine them cleverly (e.g. using some `for` loop in your shell). Read [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)